# In Windows phone,How to change checkbox state after questioning user?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, checkbox, windows-phone-8

In my app,there is a need to do this

1. At start,the checkbox is unchecked
2. user tap,and then pop up a messagebox as a alarm to make sure user indeed want to do it(At the moment the checkmark is still collapse)
3. If user click "Yes,I want to do it",then checkmark is visible and now it is checked
4. vice versa

I found that,when I tap the checkbox,**Checked** event is always triggering
*and*
the checkmark is always turn to **"checked" state**

How to solve the problem???
Any advice would be great,Thanks!!!

Comment: can you share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a trick is needed. Sharing a sample with you.

overlap a transparent background grid over your checkbox with a transparent background like this.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox Name="cb" Content="cb" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
                    <!--Grid that overlaps the checkbox-->
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" Tap="Grid_Tap_1"/> 
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

This overlapping wont call any checkbox event even if you tap on it

now in code of the event

```
    private void Grid_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
       if(MessageBox.Show("Message")==MessageBoxResult.Ok)
          {
           cb.IsChecked=True;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!I succeed in your way!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Tap Event, Try Checked and Unchecked Events of the checkbox.

Note: You can track the checked status in **"Checked" and "UnChecked" events** of the Check Box using `IsChecked` Property and write your code in appropriate events.

After Asking confirmation to user.

If the user clicks "Yes" , set `chkBox.IsChecked=true;`

else

If the user clicks "No", set `chkBox.IsChecked=false;`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to stop checkbox default behaviors. So you can create a custom control  with a image and a textbolck inside a stack panel. You should use pair of images for "Image" Control Source one for unchecked and another for checked.

```
//At start,the checkbox is unchecked
 <StackPanel x:Name="panelCheckBox" Tap="panelCheckBox_Tap_1" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Image Source="UncheckImageSourc" x:Name="ImgeCheckBox"/>
  <TextBlock Text="CheckBox Content"/>
</StackPanel>

In Code Behind
bool IsChecked=false;

 private void panelCheckBox_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
  {
   //If user click "Yes,I want to do it",then checkmark is visible and now it is checked
   if(!IsChecked)
     {
      IsChecked =true;
      ImgeCheckBox.Source = "CheckImageSource";
     }
   else
    {
     IsChecked =false;
     ImgeCheckBox.Source = "UncheckImageSourc";
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you!Also a great way,but a little hard to operate because the CheckImageSource is diffcult for me to create.Aman Khandelwal's way is nice